# How to grab data based on two parameters using a function

Tags: python, function, dataframe, for-loop, data-analysis

I am attempting to create a few plots of some wind data, however, I am having trouble selecting specific data using two parameters, that being the hour of day and month. I am attempting to use a function to find grab the specific data but instead get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Cpower18/Documents/Tryong_again.py", line 47, in <module>
    plt.plot(hr, hdh(hr, mn2))
  File "/Users/Cpower18/Documents/Tryong_again.py", line 37, in hdh
for n, k in hr, mn2:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I am currently using dataframes to sort the data based on date and a function to grab the specific data. I have managed to do so with only one variable, that being the hour of the day, however, not for two variables.

```
import csv
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

data = pd.read_csv('merged_1.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Wind Spd (km/h)'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Wind Spd (km/h)'], errors ='coerce')

df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], errors = 'coerce')

df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date/Time']))

df['hour'] = df.index.hour

df['month'] = df.index.month


mn1 = np.linspace(1, 2, 2)

mn2 = np.linspace(3, 5, 3)

mn3 = np.linspace(6, 8, 3)

mn4 = np.linspace(9, 11, 3)

mn5 = np.linspace(12)

hr = np.linspace(0, 23, 24)


def hdh(hr, mn2):
    out = []
    for n, k in hr, mn2:

        t = (df['hour'] == n) & (df['month'] == k)

        s = t['Wind Spd (km/h)'].mean(axis = 0) / 3.6

        out.append(s)

    return out

plt.plot(hr, hdh(hr, mn2))
plt.xlabel('Hour')
plt.ylabel('Wind Speed (m/s)')
plt.xlim(0, 24)
plt.ylim(2.85, 4.75)
plt.title('ShearENV Anual Average Hourly Wind Speed')
plt.grid(which = 'both', axis='both')
plt.show()`
```

The expected result should be a list of the data conforming to a specific hour (for example 01:00) and a specific season (for example months 3 to 5). As of now, I am only getting errors, thank you for any help.

Comment: If those are lists you can try `for n, k in zip(hr, mn2):`

Comment: I tried that but was met with a long string of error messages

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: It is too long to copy directly, "TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer", "ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "Wind Spd (km/h)" at position 0", "ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'Wind Spd (km/h)')", this are among a few